# faster copying of an object (like deepcopy)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, copy

I have a class in python3 that contains a few variables and represents a state.
During the program (simulation) I need to make a big amount of copies of this state so that I can change it and still have the previous information.

The problem is that `deepcopy` from the `copy` module is too slow. Would I be better of creating a method in that class to copy an object, which would create and return a new object and copy the values for each variable? Note: inside the object there is a 3D list as well.

Is there any other solution to this? The `deepcopy` is really too slow, it takes more than 99% of the execution time according to `cProfile`.

Edit: Would representing the 3D list and other lists as `numpy` arrays/matrix and copying them with `numpy` inside a custom copy function be the better way?

Comment: You can always override `__deepcopy__` and have your own algorithm there. After that calling `copy.deepcopy` will use that.

Comment: I doubt you'd be able to implement anything in pure Python what would be faster than `deepcopy` so suggest you try to think of some way to avoid the need to do it — perhaps via some sort of -copy-in-write mechanism.

Comment: I do not think that is true that you cannot do faster than deepcopy, I've had this problem before with a simpler data, a lists of lists, and used "my_list = list(map(list,my_list))" instead which works very well for a 2d list.What do you mean by copy on write?

Comment: Agree, I think whatever you are doing is too intense for python, try a different programming language. Either that or what you are doing is not optimal. Hard to say without example code. Are you bound to python by your job/project/whatever?

Comment: I'm not bound to python but it's simpler to implement and I'm already a bit too deep to change. Anyway what languages would be better? something like C is too complex with 3d lists... java?

Comment: Btw I've tried implementing with numpy and it worked a lot faster, I still have to compare results, I will do it later when I have time.

Answer (score 1):

For people from the future having the same problem:
What I did was creating a method inside the class that would manually copy the information. I did not override deepcopy, maybe that would be cleaner, maybe not.

I tried with and without numpy for 2D and 3D lists, but appending 2 numpy arrays later in the code was much more time consuming than making a sum of 2 lists (which I did need to do for my specific program).

So I used:

```
my_list = list(map(list, my_list)) # for 2D list
my_list = [list(map(list, x)) for x in my_list] # for 3D list
```